# Getting connection string from the process .NET

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, reflection, odbc

Is it possible to find out connection string(or connection details) that are used by the .NET process running on the PC?
Do a memory dump or use reflection ? Or maybe there are some SQL Server mechanisms to do that ?

Thank you

Comment: Before doing any big reverse engineering hocus-pocus we should see if it is in the application configuration file (x.exe.config for executable called x.exe). Maybe we have luck :-)

Comment: It would help a bit more if you explained why you were trying to do this.  Sure it's possible that a memory dump + examination would reveal a connection string in a .Net process.  Would be a bit labor intensive though.  Why would this be useful to you?

Comment: I have a lot of different processes, some of them are old, in some connection strings are hardcoded, some use very strange config files. Some use only one out of ten specified connection strings. The only true way would be examine running process.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the process you are looking into it may be possible to find a database connection string after doing a memory dump. That said, many proprietary applications will be so heavily obfuscated that reverse engineering the contents of the memory dump will most likely require more work than you realize. What are your goals in doing this?

Comment: They are not obfuscated, just want to make an order, and know which process is talking to what database

Answer (score 0):

Checking the connection string used in a .NET process, even if it's not obfuscated, it could be a very difficult task.

As advice, I can give you this one. If you have access to SQL Server instances, use the tool [SQL Server Profiler](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173757%28v=sql.105%29.aspx). Using this tool, you're able to listen to every query and action, that could be invoked by the process you want to analyze. In this way, maybe, you'll be able to understand which instance and which databases are used by the process.

Comment: thank you, but I am looking for more general solution, such as a service/process that will run on the box, and tell me in a real time what databases other processes are talking about, or could talk